# Why doesn't * match when + does?

Tags: regex, pcre

In the following examples (via regex101.com, PCRE mode), I can't figure out why the + quantifier finds a sub-string but * doesn't.

In the first illustration, the + quantifier (1 or more) finds all four lower-case *a* characters (which is what I expected):

[image: Plus-sign quantifier finds 1 or more as expected]

In the second illustration, the * quantifier (0 or more) doesn't find any lower-case *a* characters (which is NOT what I expected):

[image: Asterisk quantifier doesn't find 0 or more]

What REGEX logic explains why "1 or more" (+) finds all four lower-case *a* characters but "0 or more" (*) doesn't find any?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The regex engine will try to match the entire pattern at each position in the string, from left to right. The pattern `/a*/` successfully matches the zero `a`s at the very beginning of the string. This is what the little dotted caret in your regex101 screenshot signifies – a zero-width match at that position. It would match more `a`s at that position, but there are none. Nonetheless, the match is successful.

If you use a function that returns all regex matches in the string, then it will move ahead a minimum of one character each time to look for new matches, so it will match `aaaa` (as a single result) once it gets to it. Example in Python:

```python
import re
regex = r"a*"
input = "AAAAaaaaBBBBbbbb"
print(re.findall(regex, input))
```

Output:

```
['', '', '', '', 'aaaa', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

Whereas, when you use `/a+/`, it can't do those zero-width matches, so it steps through the input until it finds its first and only match at `aaaa`.

Comment: It's strange that it isn't greedy by default, or is this the convention? In Sublime it matches the whole aaaa unless you do a*? then it behaves like this.

Comment: Greedy or not, `a*` matches the zero occurrences of `a` at the start of the string, so why would the parser look further? I don't know what "Sublime" is, but it sounds broken.

Comment: @ghoti it's a Windows text editor/IDE like Notepad++ (but it's 100% free like NP++ is)... but it sounds broken to me too :P.

Comment: Sublime likely ignores zero-size matches in general just to be useful as an editor. I'm pretty sure * will behave normally (matching 0 characters as well 1+) as long as the whole match is at least 1 character in sublime.

Comment: `str = "AAAAaaaaBBBBbbbb", res = []; while ((res = /a*/.exec(str)) !== null){ console.log(res); };` do this and get your console locked up. finds infinite matches.

Comment: @RastaJedi It's not free. [Sublime Text may be downloaded and evaluated for free, however a license must be purchased for continued use.](https://www.sublimetext.com/buy)

Comment: @hvd But the evaluation period is not limited as of now. The idea is that if you use it and really like it, you might be happy enough to "donate" to the developer.

Comment: @hvd well I don't know how the word "not" was deleted from my comment, but it's too late for me to go back and edit it now. It was supposed to say 'but it's *not* 100% free like NP++ is'. And +Justin, yes, exactly, that is what I was referring to about it being at least usable without paying.

Answer (score 9):

Other answers already describe what's going on.  But for an illustration/example, try this on for size:

```
$ echo AAAAaaaabbbb | egrep -o 'a*' && echo "SUCCESS"

SUCCESS
```

The effect of grep's `-o` option is to show you only the part of the input that matched the regex.  Since what matched happened to be "zero characters", the result is empty ... but successful.

Comment: For whatever reason, when I tried that (via copy and paste) on Mint Linux 17.3, egrep displayed "aaaa" above the word SUCCESS

Comment: @RBV - interesting .. and unexpected. I don't see that behaviour in BSD grep (based on GNU grep version 2.5.1) in FreeBSD or OSX, but I can confirm similar behaviour to what you see with GNU grep 2.5.4 in Ubuntu. I can't explain this inconsistency between different GNU greps. If you search for `'z*'`, you'll also see SUCCESS.

Comment: "but I can confirm similar behaviour..." Which in my mind raises the question, which variants of egrep one can or cannot "trust" to behave predictably.

Answer (score 7):

It actually matches the beginning of the string where there are zero a's.  If you string starts with a's it will match all of them.

Answer (score 3):

At the beginning you can see the match!

[image: What]